# Addressing modes for static and local variables

Tags: gcc, static, programming-languages, addressing

Why are static variables addressed directly while locals are addressed indirectly? I cannot see where the indirection comes from for locals!

Comment: You don't provide enough context to give a good answer to this question. What programming language; what compiler etc. are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In languages that allow functions to be used recursively, locals need to be addressed indirectly (via the stack pointer).

C, however, has also static local variables, hence `static` and `local` are not necessarily mutually exclusive concepts.

Comment: @Ingro I see, so we first compute the address of the local variable and then read data from the computed memory address. Right?

Comment: It depends, of course, on the implementation, but a common thing to do is to let a register (the stack pointer) point to the top/bottom of the stack and then every local variable has a known offset from that stack pointer.